# Difference between ./* (star) and ./*.* (star dot star)

Tags: bash

Is it the same for using ./* or ./*.* ?

For instance, if I try

```
chmod 755 ./* -R
```

or

```
chmod 755 ./*.* -R
```

It will get the same results, making the files and directories here using 755 permission. But I would want to know is there any different part of concept between these two methods?

Comment: Not the same -- look at whether permissions changed for files with no `.`s in their names.

Comment: BTW, this has been asked and answered already, but it's hard to search for, so it's taking a minute for me to find a duplicate to close it against. (Similarly, can't blame you much for not being able to find the already-existing instance). ...indeed, ended up giving up, and editing the phrase "star dot star" in to make *this* version, at least, be searchable for folks in the future.

Comment: (Aside, to other readers re: the ongoing close vote: I do agree that this might be eligible for close as being a better fit for one of our sister sites, such as [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), as shell globs are in no meaningful way "unique to software development", as ANDed into other conditions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- or "close as dupe", if anyone can actually find the prior  instance. That said, I'm also pretty sure that close-as-lacking-MCVE *isn't* appropriate for this one, since it isn't a question that seeks debugging help).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you very much, yes it hard for me to find whether there were a duplicate question. And next time I will put my question to Unix forum, Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*.*` (aka "star dot star", or "asterisk period asterisk") limits your glob to only match files with `.`s in their names. By contrast, `*` alone has no such limitation, and will match files with no `.`s in their names at all, *in addition to* also matching files with names containing `.`s.

MS-DOS was designed such that *all* files had extensions, by having a three-character extension field always present inside the filesystem's directory structure (even if those extensions were empty), so `*.*` was a global wildcard there -- but this has never been true on UNIXlike systems, so folks typing `*.*` are presumably doing so as a habit carried over from other platforms.

Comment: Thank you for your detail reply. I had tried these two way by myself. Yes, They are different. I think the more safe way is using both "star" and " star dot star " at the same time, how do you think about this?

Comment: If you use them both at the same time, then files with dots in them will be added to the argument list twice (once from the `*` glob, and again from the `*.*`); there's no reason to do that, vs the no-dot version. Processing files twice will make a command like `chmod` a little slower, but also means you'll hit the operating system's maximum-command-line-length limit faster.

Comment: ...I've edited the answer to try to be a little more clear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in three ways. For testing first make a directory. "a" by `mkdir a`, also touch a new text file "b.txt" and directory "c" in folder "a". Then touch a "f.txt" text file in "c" folder.

> `a-----|- b.txt
>        |
>        |- c - f.txt`

`chown root:root a`      ----> make only "a" folder permission to root

`chown root:root a/*`    ----> make files and directories in "a" permission to root but not "a" folder-self and not "f.txt" in "c" directory.

`chown root:root a/*.*`  ----> make files in "a" permission to root but not "a" folder-self and directories in "a" and not "f.txt" in "c" directory.

and try `-R` argument

`chown -R root:root a`      ----> make files in "a" permission to root and directories in "a" and "f.txt" in "c" folder to root as well as "a" folder-self

`chown -R root:root a/*`    ----> make files in "a" permission to root and directories in "a" and "f.txt" in "c" folder to root but not "a" folder-self

`chown -R root:root a/*.*`  ----> make files in "a" permission to root but not directories in "a", "f.txt" in "c" folder and "a" folder-self